# Range of values as ELSE clause in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc which is supposed to filter results based on an integer which can be `NULL` and I need to be able to choose results that either match the integer or retrieve all results but I can't figure out the syntax for the "All" results part. Query is basically this:

```
Select * from dbo.TABLE 
WHERE [IDField] = 
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(@ID, 0) > 0 THEN @ID 
    ELSE ????? 
  END
```

I want to use an `IN` range to include all the values because setting it to `0` or `Null` will return no results, but this doesn't work:

```
Select * from dbo.TABLE 
WHERE [IDField] = 
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(@ID, 0) > 0 THEN @ID 
    ELSE 1 OR 2 OR 3 
  END
```

or this:

```
Select * from dbo.TABLE 
WHERE [IDField] IN (
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(@mID, 0) > 0 THEN @mID 
    ELSE 1,2,3 
  END
)
```

Comment: Your problem statement is not very clear, but I think you want something like `...WHERE [IDField] = @ID OR 1 = 1`.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use case _expressions_ in WHERE (and ON) clauses. Stick to AND/OR instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrase this without the `case`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TABLE 
WHERE @id is null OR IDField = @id;
```

Then you can expand this to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TABLE 
WHERE (COALESCE(@ID, 0) > 0 AND IDField = @id) OR
      IDField IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `Coalesce` didn't work, but the rest of it was spot on. I ended up with this `(@ID = 0 AND [IDField] in (1,2,3)) OR [IDfield] = @ID` becuase my null value was being set to 0 elsewhere in the procedure. Thanks.